# namespaceとscope moduleの違いがわかりません

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

namespaceとscope moduleでの違いがrake routesで見てる限りではprefixの違いだけのように思います。

何か他に違いがあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

namespaceとscope moduleではprefix(`〇〇_path`のメソッド名)のほかURIが異なります。

`namespace :admin` とするとURIも`/admin/hogehoge`と頭に`/admin`がつきます。
一方`scope module: :admin`としてもURIは`/hogehoge`となり`/admin`はつきません。

controllerを置く場所がどちらも`admin`ディレクトリ以下に置かないといけないのはどちらも変わりません。

[こちら](https://qiita.com/blueplanet/items/522cc8364f6cf189ecad)に詳しくまとめられています。